Mongodb does not finish query after many requests
I'm testing my application with gatling.
The tested endpoint is the login, which must return user information.
The function searches two collections sequentially, not in parallel.
The problem occurs when we increase the number of requests to a level like: 1,500 users per second.
Gatling warns of premature closure
17:18:39,281 [WARN] i.g.h.e.r.DefaultStatsProcessor - 'Auth Prod' request for user 12053 failed: j.i.IOException: premature close
17:18:39.281 [WARN] i.g.h.e.GatlingHttpListener - 'Auth Prod' request for user 12077 failed

But the big problem is that even after we stop testing, the server does not respond to login requests again.
The queries get stuck, not returning any errors, only after a long time does the server come back.
After gatling returned the errors, I made a request via postman to the endpoint, and only after 5m 35s did the request return. Typically returned within 15ms
The Rust server is still up, only queries are hanging.
This is probably related to pool size and maximum connections, but I wouldn't want to change them for now, just so the server doesn't crash during queries.
Rust
let mut client_options = ClientOptions::parse_async(uri).await?;
client_options.max_idle_time = Some(Duration::new(10, 0));

let client = Client::with_options(client_options)?;

in each request I use the following function to obtain the client ref and access the collection.
pub fn get_service<T>(&self, service: Services) -> Collection<T> {
    let client = self.cliente.clone();
    let database = client.database(&self.database);

    match service {
        Services::User => database.collection::<T>("users"),
        Services::GrupoEmp => database.collection::<T>("emps"),
    }
}

Query
let find_options = FindOneOptions::builder().max_time(Duration::from_secs(5)).build();
let user: User = match user_service
    .find_one(
        doc! {"login": &user_name},
        Some(find_options),
    )
    .await // Dead

I'm using

Mongodb Rust Driver
Axum
Docker

Obs: there are several improvements that can be made so that the server can support multiple requests, such as load balancer, replications, etc., but the problem is that the queries are dying.
Edit1
# rust and mongodb container
# ulimit -a
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
data(kbytes)         unlimited
stack(kbytes)        8192
coredump(blocks)     0
memory(kbytes)       unlimited
locked memory(kbytes) 64
process              unlimited
nofiles              1024
vmemory(kbytes)      unlimited
locks                unlimited
rtprio               0


Is it possible you are hitting a resource limit from outstanding connections? If you're on linux, see what ulimit -n (open file limit) says.

@kmdreki, I edited the post adding the output of the ulimit -a command, I did this inside the mongo container and rust container, same result, right?

1,500 connections with nofiles 1024 is a bit of a problem but I don't think it would cause the symptoms you describe, especially if your Rust server uses the default 10 connections to MongoDB. "The queries get stuck" - do they actually resolve slowly and sequentially (such that the last ones appear "stuck" for a long while)?

@kmdreko Well, after gatling returned the errors, I made a request via postman to the endpoint, and only after 5m 35s did the request return. Typically returned within 15ms

By default the mongod log should report any query that takes longer than 100ms.  Does the log provide any clues what was hanging around after the test?

If other clients have the same issue then this question is probably more appropriate for DBA or Server Fault, because it sounds like it's more about the MongoDB service than it is about Rust.
